# How to fix the vulnerable to SOQL injection attacks error in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, soql, soql-injection

In my Custom Visualforce page U have coded an iframe like this:

```
$("a#icsFrame8").click(function () {
    document.getElementById("myIFrame").src = '/apex/Samplepage?isdtp=mn';
```

But, After we did a BURP scan the passed URL parameter appears to be vulnerable to SOQL injection attack error.

Below it shows the Error:

> GET
>   /apex/SamplePage?id=a0Pb0000007FkR9EAK&isdtp=mn&137665543'%20or%20'4694'%3d'4694=1
>   HTTP/1.

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: What did you already do to fix the issue?

Comment: Also, read this https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_SQL_Injection

Comment: What does `137665543'%20or%20'4694'%3d'4694=1` do?

Answer (score 1):

That's a false positive.

I mean, man, *do you really trust a machine judging your code?* :-)

That "error" line you reported (actually, an HTTP request) seems to be a complete artifact by the BURP test engine, which invented it by itself and not by taking advantage of any holes in your code - at least standing at the few lines you pasted in here.